# TabPanel switch error

Tags: visualforce, tabpanel

I'm using a tabPanel and cannot get the tabs to switch.
When I move the mouse over to or click on a tab, I see this error:

> > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
> >         3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.PrototypeScript:107
> >     Element.Methods.removeClassName
> >           3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.PrototypeScript:107
> >     RichFaces.outTab tabPanel.js:18  onmouseout

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none">
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="the1stTab" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
    <apex:tab label="abc" title="abc" name="the1stTab" id="the1stTab">
        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="def" title="def" name="the2ndTab" id="the2ndTab">
        </apex:tab>
   <\apex:tabPanel>
<\apex:outputPanel>
```

Any advise why this happens?

Comment: Something isn't being initialized correctly. Can you post a snippet of your JavaScript and VF?

Comment: Its not my JS, I think it's SF JS

Comment: Did you try a different browser? Ensure that JS on the browser is not turned off.

Comment: I didn't try other browsers because I'm using tabpanel on other pages and it is working fine. It is something specific to this page

Comment: I faced the same issue and i solved it.Please find the link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21207/display-the-data-on-click-of-tab/21533#21533

Answer (score 8):

I just saw this happen on a Visualforce page I was developing. It appears to be a conflict of jQuery.

I added this code, and it resolved the issue for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

From there, anywhere you reference jQuery, use `j$` instead of `$`

Answer (score -1):

You Can use,
`JQuery.noConflict()` or Simple      `$.noConflict()` for avoiding JQuery Conflict in script tag.